# How to load all partitions by scripting in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a S3 `bucket: s3://bucket-name/year=2018/month=xx/day=xx/hour=xx/minute=xx.`

Correspondingly, I have 5 partition columns on my AWS Athena table (year, month, day, hour, minute).

I want to load all data in Oct. I tried to

```
ALTER TABLE table_name add partition (all 5 partitions)
location "s3://data/year=xx/month=xx/.......";
```

However, I have to write this "alter table" command for all minute-level partitions, which is impossible.

Is it possible to write a script in AWS Athena to load all partitions?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using MSCK REPAIR TABLE command.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html

First of all, you need to create a table similar to the one below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `example`(
col1 string,
col2 string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
`year` int, `year` `month`,`day`,`hour`,`minute`)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
's3://data'
```

After that you should be able to run "MSCK REPAIR TABLE" command.

If you want continue using the "alter table add parition" command you will need to create custom script. In this case it will be usuful boto3 or jdbc athena driver:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html